# Arrange foreach loop in asc order Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

How do I arrange a foreach loop in ascending order with Laravel?
Here's my current code:

```
                    <h2 class="title">Top Performing Schools</h2>
                    @foreach($sch as $sch)
                    <div class="sch">
                        <div class="sch-content">
                            <a href="{{$sch->url}}">
                                <img style="width:60px;vertical-align: middle;" src="{{asset('images/'.$sch->logo)}}">
                                {{$sch->name}}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

My guess is that `$result = $result->orderBy('ranking_philippines', 'asc');` has to be put somewhere.  `ranking_philippines` is the database field that contains the ranking data that I want the items to be sorted by.

Comment: show your action related ..  the code where you obatin the result form db

Comment: That IS the code used to obtain the results from the database.  That's my front-end code.

Comment: we need  your backend code  ..  the code that you use before call the frontend (render your view) rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Phil, we have to do some wild guessing here. Let's presume your table is called `schools` and the model `School`.

The controller, let's call it `SchoolController` should look like this:

```
public function getRanking() {
  $scores = School::orderBy('ranking_philippines', 'asc')->get();
  return view('schools.ranking', compact('scores'));
}
```

Then in `resources/views/schools/ranking.blade.php` you have to get something like this:

```
             <h2 class="title">Top Performing Schools</h2>
                @foreach($scores as $score)
                <div class="sch">
                    <div class="sch-content">
                        <a href="{{$score->url}}">
                            <img style="width:60px;vertical-align: middle;" src="{{asset('/images/'.$score->logo)}}">
                            {{$score->name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

I hope that gives you some help. You have to help us too Phil by being more specific. No offense. I understand. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Not really the solution BUT I'll give it to you.  You took the time to give a pretty solid answer.  Basically, I went to my pagesController.php file and edited the `public function index(){` function.  Edited this part: `$school=schools::where('status','')`  It has this line which I edited: `->orderByRaw('convert((CASE WHEN ranking_philippines IS NULL then 129999999999999 ELSE ranking_philippines END),unsigned) asc')
       ->take(4)
       ->get();`